# Page doesn't reload the data when other page not finished loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having difficulties in my current project when I'm loading data in other window (estimated 5seconds), when I try again to load another page at the same time which occur only (2 seconds). The second request is waiting for the after of the second request finished.

how can load the page data without depending on other pages processing?

Here is my Ajax code:

```
 $.each(_arrayList, function (index, value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: '{RootEnquiryID: "' + _RootEnquiryID.toString() + '", ToCompanyNumber: "' + value + '", BincludeAttachement: "' + _BincludeAttachement + '", isAdvertiser: "' + "1" + '", Classification: "' + _Classification + '", Message: "' + _Message + '"}',
                url: "../ECMonitoring.asmx/RouteEnquiry",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (parseInt(data) > 0) {
                        //success
                    } else {
                        //error
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Combine Error:" + errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function () { }
            });
        }, 50)
    });
```

Please advise,

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you using ajax to load data?

Comment: I've tried postback and ajax. those are not working for me.

Comment: same result both of them.

Comment: Show me your ajax method

Comment: @Damith, please see the code above.

Comment: Seems like your method looks fine. But try to avoid it calling inside loop and try putting `processData: true` in your ajax method  .But i am not sure it will fix your problem.Basically `async: true` should fix your problem and check that you have it in all methods